# Cloning a dual boot SSD to larger SSD

Tags: dual-boot, dd, clone

I have just completed cloning my original 256Gb drive to a new 1TB SSD using dd. The original drive initially came with W11 on it and I added dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 but the Ubuntu stopped working. Now I want to delete any unnecessary partitions on the new drive and re-add the Ubuntu dual boot but not sure which partitions can be safely deleted. Have attached partition table produced from Ubuntu. [image]

Comment: Linux partitions are ext4 and swap. You also have two ESP - efi system partitions, most systems only work with one, although you can have multiple FAT32 partitions just not with boot,esp flags. NTFS, ESP, & reserved are all used by Windows. If reinstalling Ubuntu use existing ESP. Make sure you have backed up any data you want in any partitions you delete. Default install is normally just / (root) with ESP for UEFI boot. Swap is now a file unless you already have a swap partition or really want one. Many suggest separating system (root) from data,  /home or data in /home in another partition.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over your partitions according to type:

## fat32,boot,esp

You have two boot or EFI system partitions. You need to figure out which one is actually used to boot your system. If the other one is used for chainloading, then you need to merge the other partition into it, and point whatever was writing to it to the actually used partition.

## unknown,Microsoft reserved partition

Some versions of Windows use this for boot data. It's small, so I wouldn't risk it.

## ntfs

This is likely your Windows 11 install you want to keep.

## ext4

You have an ext4 for each mount point. You need to find which partition was your root drive. Then you can delete all others after moving the files to it. Update `/etc/fstab` after.

## linux-swap

Safe to delete. Update `/etc/fstab` after.

## ntfs,hidden,diag

This is the Windows recovery partition. It is safe to delete.

Comment: thanks, that was very helpful.. I presume as I'm removing all ubuntu components, there is no needed 'Update /etc/fstab'